# Eager Loading in a Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to reduce the number of database queries in my Rails 3 app.

User model:

```
has_many :agreements
```

Agreement model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

The agreements table has two user id fields... payer_id and payee_id. Is it possible to make something like the following work:

```
user_payer_agreements = current_user.agreements
user_payee_agreements = current_user.agreements
```

I could use user_id for one side of the transaction but I need to get both sides. Is it possible to specify payer_id or payee_id instead of user_id in the process of creating an association? If not, do i need use a join or a sql statement. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
has_many :payer_agreements, :class_name => 'Agreement', :foreign_key => :payer_id
has_many :payee_agreements, :class_name => 'Agreement', :foreign_key => :payee_id
```

With this you can do:

```
current_user.payer_agreements
current_user.payee_agreements
```

Is this what you are looking for?